# I am having issues with permissions of the apache user www-data on raspberry pi

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a website where the user needs to submit their name and last name into the form and then I need it to create a text file with the results of whatever the user put in and store it on the server. The location I want it saved is in a folder at /var/www/html/text/fields.txt
**This is my code I want to run.**  1.HTML(sendmessage.html) 2. PHP- (Action-page.php)

```
    <div class="messageform">
          <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['firstname'] ) && isset( $_POST['lastname'] ) ) {
    // Manage our constants easier up top in one place
    $TextFilePath = './var/www/html/text';
    $FileName = 'fields.txt';
    $FullPathAndFileName = "$TextFilePath$FileName";

    // Create our data to write
    $txt = $_POST['firstname'].' - '.$_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOL; 
    
    // Validate dir exists, if not, create it
    if (!is_dir($TextFilePath))
        mkdir($TextFilePath, 0755, true);

    // Open/create our file to write to
    $file = fopen($FullPathAndFileName, "w") or die("Can't find or create $FileName");

    // Write out the form data
    fwrite($file, $txt);

    // Close the file
    fclose($file);



}
```

**Note that the HTML one is just the form part of the code, not the whole thing.**

The code works in vs studio but whenever I run it on apache(raspberry pi) it seems to work but when I look at the files it never is made.

**Any help is appreciated and just to let you know I have tried some guides online.**

Comment: I am currently testing, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It didn't create the directory I tried by changing the permission from 0755 to 0744

Comment: OK, IT WORKS YAY but it made a directory so now it looks like /var/www/html/var/www/html but that's fine it works :)